# Java : Is String.replace GC overhead too much?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

Given the code :

```
long i=0;
while(i++<MILLIONS){
    String justHex = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-","");
    System.out.println(justHex);
}
```

This will produce lots of unique strings, which gc will have to clean ultimately. And, `enter code here`doing replaceAll on each strings will create even more unique strings (twice?).

Whether this(replaceAll) is a significant overhead for GC for a small application?

Should a programmer worry about such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are temporary strings, and will not be referenced anymore in the next iteration, so I expect them to be quickly garbage collected. Unless benchmarks indicate that the loop is a performance bottleneck, don't worry too much about it and focus on functional correctness.

A bigger impact on both memory usage and performance will be the fact that you use `replaceAll`, which expects a *regular expression* as first argument. If you don't need a regular expression, it's better to use `replace`, which also replaces all occurrences, but does not have the regular expression overhead.

Comment: Actually, replace also does regular expression replacement (replace invokes replaceAll), but first escapes all the special characters in the string. If you want best performance, you should probably look at third-party libraries from Apache or Google (source for `replace`: `return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));`